# C++ - With associative array, can't search by key after sorting by value

Tags: c++, search, associative-array, quicksort, binary-search

In the below code, I have an associative array which contains the letters of the alphabet as keys and an arbitrary value associated with them.  I have implemented a quick sort function to sort them based on value descending.  I have a binary search function to search for a particular key (letter).  The binary search works fine before I sort, but after I sort only some of the letters are found using it.  Trying to work through it on my own, I looped through the array before and after executing quickSort() and it seems to confirm that those values still exist, though they are sorted.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int arr[][2], int value, int left, int right)
{
    while (left <= right)
    {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[middle][0] == value)
            return middle;
        else if (arr[middle][0] > value)
            right = middle - 1;
        else
            left = middle + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void quickSort(int arr[][2], int left, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp1, tmp2;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2][1];

    /* partition */
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (arr[i][1] > pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j][1] < pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            tmp1 = arr[i][0];
            tmp2 = arr[i][1];

            arr[i][0] = arr[j][0];
            arr[i][1] = arr[j][1];

            arr[j][0] = tmp1;
            arr[j][1] = tmp2;

            i++;

            j--;
        }
    };

    /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);

}

int main()
{
    const int alphLength = 26;
    int assocArr[alphLength][2] = { {'A', 5},  {'B', 2}, {'C', 4}, {'D', 3},  {'E', 1}, {'F', 0}, {'G', 0}, {'H', 0}, {'I', 0},
        {'J', 0}, {'K', 0}, {'L', 0}, {'M', 0}, {'N', 0}, {'O', 0}, {'P', 75}, {'Q', 0}, {'R', 0},
        {'S', 0}, {'T', 0}, {'U', 0}, {'V', 0}, {'W', 0}, {'X', 50}, {'Y', 0}, {'Z', 100} };

char a;
char searchLetter = 'Z';

for (int i = 0; i < alphLength; i++)
{
    a = assocArr[i][0];
    cout << "index " << i << ": " << a << endl;
}

cout << "found " << searchLetter << " before quickSort() at " << binarySearch(assocArr, searchLetter, 0, alphLength-1) << endl;

quickSort(assocArr, 0, alphLength-1);

for (int i = 0; i < alphLength; i++)
{
    a = assocArr[i][0];
    cout << "index " << i << ": " << a << endl;
}

cout << "found " << searchLetter << " after quickSort() at " << binarySearch(assocArr, searchLetter, 0, alphLength-1) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search only works on sorted arrays, and they need to be sorted by the same criteria which you use to compare them in your search. Your array starts out sorted by letter ascending, and your binary search searches by letter ascending, so this works. You then sort it by value, which scrambles the letters. You then do binary search by letter ascending again, which won't work because the array is no longer sorted by letter ascending.